# Tab Auto-Completion in Mac OS X when using sftp in terminal

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, shell, sftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab Auto-Completion in Mac OS X when using sftp in terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/484745/tab-auto-completion-in-mac-os-x-when-using-sftp-in-terminal)

i have been getting very frustrated lately since the `readline` functionality has been removed from MacOSX and Tab Auto-Completion doesn't work anymore.

So i was wondering if anyone knew a good alternative to use that i could install so i can tab auto-complete files when sftp'd in.

I heard that [with-readline](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/sw/withreadline.html) is a good option for this. If so, how do i get an `alias sftp = with-readline sftp` to work?

I would like to do the same with any other option that isn't with-readline, so i don't have to assign an alias each time i set up a session.

I am using Mac OS X 10.8(Mountain Lion)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.