# Tab Auto-Completion in Mac OS X when using sftp in terminal

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, sftp

i have been getting very frustrated lately since the `readline` functionality has been removed from MacOSX and Tab Auto-Completion doesn't work anymore.

So i was wondering if anyone knew a good alternative to use that i could install so i can tab auto-complete files when sftp'd in.

I heard that [with-readline](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/sw/withreadline.html) is a good option for this. If so, how do i get an `alias sftp = with-readline sftp` to work?

I would like to do the same with any other option that isn't with-readline, so i don't have to assign an alias each time i set up a session.

I am using Mac OS X 10.8(Mountain Lion) with Homebrew installed.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could just install the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) `openssh` port which includes an `sftp` built with tab completion.

Comment: im using homebrew, i don't want to install macports because those two begin misbehaving, if i'm not mistaken. I should have probably specified that i was running homebrew.