# How to change the behaviour of "tab" key from "Insert a tab" to "Completion" in sftp CLI in Windows Terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal, windows-11, sftp, windows-terminal

I am recently switching from Ubuntu to Windows 11 and found this feature not working:

In Ubuntu terminal, when I am using sftp CLI, `Tab` means to complete the file/folder name in the directory.

However, in Windows Terminal, when using sftp CLI, `Tab` means inserting a tab.

Can I change the `Tab` behaviour to be the same to that in Ubuntu?

P.S. I think this issue is somewhat similar to [Tab Auto-Completion in Mac OS X when using sftp in terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/484475/tab-auto-completion-in-mac-os-x-when-using-sftp-in-terminal), which in his case it is MacOS instead of Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of <kbd>Tab</kbd> is partially defined by the program. For tab-completion to work, the program needs to set the terminal to character-at-a-time mode (raw mode) instead of the default line mode, and to internally process all input (arrow keys, backspacing, etc) instead of leaving it to the tty layer.

The `sftp` client from OpenSSH uses the *libedit* library for input editing and tab-completion (similar to the more common readline), so these features will be active only if `sftp.exe` has been compiled with libedit support. Unfortunately, the Microsoft builds of OpenSSH do not use libedit so you only get what the OS terminal layer provides. You'd need to maintain your own Win32-OpenSSH builds, or use some other variant (maybe the MSYS OpenSSH from "Git for Windows" or the Cygwin OpenSSH) that has it.

(I would also suggest using the `lftp` FTP&SFTP client instead, as it has a more pleasant CLI, but unfortunately doesn't seem to be available for Windows at all.)

A relevant GitHub issue for Win32-OpenSSH has been closed by a developer assuming that the tty layer should handle tab completion – which is indeed a feature on Windows, where Conhost handles tab-completion when using Cmd.exe, but doesn't allow completing *remote* filenames in situations where sftp.exe would support that.